# rsync to local USB disk gives "rsync error 2 (Protocol incompatibility)

Tags: rsync, xfs

I am using backintime for backup which in turn uses rsync to make snapshots.
Most filesystems on the computer are XFS, including the rsync target,
system is Ubuntu 20.04 with rsync version 3.1.3  protocol version 31.

I get an exit code `2` from rsync which is `Protocol incompatibility`,
and some digging shows this happens if you are running rsync across some (ssh) connection
between two computers with different rsync versions, or login scripts injecting some unexpected output into the ssh connection. None of that is the case here, this is all local,
see below for the command line.

=> Anymore insights into this rsync error ? How can a local `Protocol incompatibility` happen
if there is just one `/usr/bin/rsync` ?

Yours,
Steffen

The local USB disk mounted as
`type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota,uhelper=udisks2)`

```
INFO: Call rsync to take the snapshot
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
WARNING: Command "rsync --recursive --times --devices --specials --hard-links --human-readable \
--links --acls --xattrs --perms --executability --group --owner --info=progress2 \
--no-inc-recursive --delete --delete-excluded -v -i \
--out-format=BACKINTIME: %i %n%L --link-dest=../../20210301-082432-781/backup \
--chmod=Du+wx --exclude=/media/sneumann/LinuxBackup/msbi-corei \
--exclude=/root/.local/share/backintime --exclude=.local/share/backintime/mnt \
--exclude=.gvfs --exclude=.cache* --exclude=[Cc]ache* --exclude=.thumbnails* \
--exclude=[Tt]rash* --exclude=*.backup* --exclude=*~ \
--exclude=/home/sneumann/Ubuntu One --exclude=.dropbox* --exclude=/proc/* \
--exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/media \
--exclude=/root/.local/share/backintime/takesnapshot_.log \
--exclude=/root/.local/share/backintime --include=/ --include=/** \
--exclude=* / /media/sneumann/LinuxBackup/msbi-corei/backintime/msbi-corei/root/1/new_snapshot/backup" 
returns 2
```

Comment: Run the command  by hand (maybe add `-n`) and look at the debug message. You can find all the possibilities by running something like `grep -r -B5 RERR_PROTOCOL` on the rsync source.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce yet, will keep trying, but thanks for the hint. Yours, Steffen